# How to set xPath of Java Selenium when there are two table of same class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I trying to test this [WEBSITE](https://google.com/code-search) table data by using Java Selenium but there are two tables on the webpage with same class name `datatable`. When I set as:

```
private final static String table   = "//table[contains(@class,'datatable')]";
```

then its scraping first table on the page and once its given both tables data of first page.

How can I set xPath separately for each table with one class on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use indexes like

```
private final static String tablefirst   = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[1]"; 
private final static String tablelast   = "(//table[contains(@class,'datatable')])[last()]";
```

---

You can use below xpath as well. more generic.

```
private final static String tablefirst   = "//p[text()='Found 1096 Airline Codes']/following::table[1]"; 
private final static String tablelast   = "//p[text()='Found 9130 Location Codes']/following::table[1]";
```

Comment: I was trying to accept but page started time 3 minutes to accept it. Just finished and I clicked. Thanks from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy if you know, and from your question I assume you know which is first and which is second table. In that case use:

```
driver.findelements(By.xpath("//table[contains(@class,'datatable')]")).get(index)
```

if you want first table

```
index=0
```

if you want secondtable

```
index=1
```